# No output in console when querying DB with java

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

Trying to do a homework assignment involving connecting java to Oracle SQLdeveloper using jdbc and then returning some select statements to start out. I have gotten the database up and added the AUTHORS table to my DB. When I query in sqldeveloper using "select * from authors;", I get this result, which is correct:

```
 AUTHORID FIRSTNAME            LASTNAME                     
  ---------- -------------------- ------------------------------
     1 Paul                 Deitel                        
     2 Harvey               Deitel                        
     3 Abbey                Deitel                        
     4 Dan                  Quirk                         
     5 Michael              Morgano
```

My java class is as such:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {

public static void main(String args[]) throws 
ClassNotFoundException {

    try {
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";
    String user = "SYSTEM";
    String pass = "myvalidpassword";

    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, pass);
    if (c != null)
    {
        System.out.println("You're in your database now");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Failed to make connection");
    }

    System.out.println("Starting queries..");
    Statement myStmt = c.createStatement();

    ResultSet rset = myStmt.executeQuery("select * from authors");
    System.out.println(rset);
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rset.getMetaData();
    int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
    System.out.println(metaData);
    System.out.println(numberOfColumns);

    if (rset.next()) {
        for (int i= 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
            System.out.print(metaData.getColumnLabel(i) + "\t");
        }
      }
    }

    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

I have entered a lot of print statements to make sure it is indeed connecting to the DB. Those print statements do go through to the console:

```
You're in your database now
Starting queries..
oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@46d59067
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetMetaData@14bdbc74
3
```

So, the console correctly sees there are three columns but Result Set comes back with the strange at symbol and numbers. I am expecting it to come back with details regarding the table. I have googled and can't seem to find an answer, I also tried disconnecting my instance by going to the SQL > prompt in command line and doing shutdown in case my java file is trying to open an already open connection, but that just changed my instance to idle.

Comment: The `@` symbol print out represents the memory location where the object is stored. This normally means the object you're trying to print to console doesn't have a `toString()` method. In this instance `ResultSetMetaData` and `ResultSet` does not override `toString()`. Check to see if the objects in question have a method that will print a string out

Comment: You need to iterate over the result set, get values for the columns you want to print and print it yourself. `ResultSet` implementations usually do not override `toString()` and if they do they will certainly not print out rows, because that doesn't make sense for how it is supposed to be used.